# Sending Email through Lotus Notes using Excel

Tags: vba, email, excel

I'm writing a macro code to send email through *IBM Lotus Notes*, I'm able to send to customers, but with wrong content, I have saved the content of the email in worksheet "General Overview" at here:

```
Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

But it will auto send to one customer an email with wrong content like yes and no, I'm now clueless about this and will appreciate much for your help.

Here's the whole part:

```
Sub Send_Unformatted_Rangedata(i As Integer)
Dim noSession As Object, noDatabase As Object, noDocument As Object
Dim vaRecipient As Variant
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim Data As DataObject
Dim rngGen As Range
Dim rngApp As Range
Dim rngspc As Range

Dim stSubject As String
stSubject = "E-Mail For Approval for " + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value) + "  for the Project  " + Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
'Const stMsg As String = "Data as part of the e-mail's body."
'Const stPrompt As String = "Please select the range:"

'This is one technique to send an e-mail to many recipients but for larger
'number of recipients it's more convenient to read the recipient-list from
'a range in the workbook.
vaRecipient = VBA.Array(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value, Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "V").Value)

 On Error Resume Next
'Set rnBody = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=stPrompt, _
     Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
 'The user canceled the operation.
'If rnBody Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Set rngGen = Nothing
 Set rngApp = Nothing
 Set rngspc = Nothing

 Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngApp = Sheets("Application").Range("A1:E13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 Set rngspc = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "Q").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngspc = Union(rngspc, Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "R").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

  On Error GoTo 0

  If rngGen Is Nothing And rngApp Is Nothing And rngspc Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
      Exit Sub
  End If

'Instantiate Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

'Make sure Lotus Notes is open and available.
If noDatabase.IsOpen = False Then noDatabase.OPENMAIL

'Create the document for the e-mail.
Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument

'Copy the selected range into memory.
rngGen.Copy
rngApp.Copy
rngspc.Copy

'Retrieve the data from then copied range.
Set Data = New DataObject
Data.GetFromClipboard

'Add data to the mainproperties of the e-mail's document.
With noDocument
    .Form = "Memo"
    .SendTo = vaRecipient
    .Subject = stSubject
    'Retrieve the data from the clipboard.
    .Body = Data.GetText & " " & stMsg
    .SaveMessageOnSend = True
End With

'Send the e-mail.
With noDocument
    .PostedDate = Now()
    .send 0, vaRecipient
End With

'Release objects from memory.
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing

'Activate Excel for the user.
'Change Microsoft Excel to Excel
AppActivate "Excel"

'Empty the clipboard.
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed.", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub Send_Formatted_Range_Data(i As Integer)
Dim oWorkSpace As Object, oUIDoc As Object
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim lnRetVal As Long
Dim stTo As String
Dim stCC As String
Dim stSubject As String
Const stMsg As String = "An e-mail has been succesfully created and saved."

Dim rngGen As Range
Dim rngApp As Range
Dim rngspc As Range

stTo = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value
stCC = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "V").Value
stSubject = "E-Mail For Approval for " + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value) + "  for the Project  " + Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")

'Check if Lotus Notes is open or not.
lnRetVal = FindWindow("NOTES", vbNullString)

If lnRetVal = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please make sure that Lotus Notes is open!", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngApp = Sheets("Application").Range("A1:E13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 Set rngspc = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "Q").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set rngspc = Union(rngspc, Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "R").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
 On Error GoTo 0

If rngGen Is Nothing And rngApp Is Nothing And rngspc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

rngGen.Copy
rngApp.Copy
rngspc.Copy

'Instantiate the Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set oWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

On Error Resume Next

Set oUIDoc = oWorkSpace.ComposeDocument("", "mail\xldennis.nsf", "Memo")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oUIDoc = oWorkSpace.CurrentDocument

'Using LotusScript to create the e-mail.
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("EnterSendTo", stTo)
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("EnterCopyTo", stCC)
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("Subject", stSubject)

'If You experience any issues with the above three lines then replace it with:
'Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("EnterSendTo", stTo)
'Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("EnterCopyTo", stCC)
'Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Subject", stSubject)

'The can be used if You want to add a message into the created document.
Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Body", vbNewLine & stBody)

'Here the selected range is pasted into the body of the outgoing e-mail.
Call oUIDoc.GoToField("Body")
Call oUIDoc.Paste

'Save the created document.
Call oUIDoc.Save(True, False, False)
'If the e-mail also should be sent then add the following line.
'Call oUIDoc.Send(True)

'Release objects from memory.
Set oWorkSpace = Nothing
Set oUIDoc = Nothing

With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox stMsg, vbInformation

'Activate Lotus Notes.
 AppActivate ("Notes")
'Last edited Feb 11, 2015 by Peter Moncera

End Sub
```

Comment: With the copying into the memory. Would the next copy replace the last copy? So you are doing `rngGen.copy`, `rngApp.copy`, `rngspc.copy` But wouldnt that all be replaced with `rngspc.copy` as this is the most recent to be copied into memory. I am pretty sure that excel can only have 1 thing in the clipboard

Comment: @Sam Thank you, do you know how to send the email manually?

Answer (score 0):

The clipboard will get replaced by the multiple copies you do.

To be able to see the email and manually send it add this

`CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace").EDITDOCUMENT True, oUIDoc
AppActivate "> " & oUIDoc.subject`

Below
`Call oUIDoc.Save(True, False, False)`

Cannot test to see if that will work correctly as no longer have lotus notes. But this is simular to what I used in my last job.

Comment: Sorry I can only try it tomorrow cuz my laptop could not connect to internet at home.

Comment: hi the method seems no working, the error message says `Object required`

Comment: Is it failing on the `AppActivate` part? If so replace `oUIDoc.subject` to `stSubject`

Comment: It's  falling on `Call oUIDoc.Save(True, False, False)`

Comment: Did it fail on that before? As that was already part of your code

Comment: Sorry its falling on `CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace").EDITDOCUMENT True, oUIDoc`